# simple hide/show behavior....best practice?

Tags: xpages

It is embarrassing that I am having these 'newby' questions a lot, as I am late to the XPages rodeo for real work.   Please be gentle.

This is BASIC functionality, needing to have a field that is initially hidden on new pages, until another combobox gets set to a certain value (think of any generic 'other' field, that is only displayed if "Other" is selected in the main field.).

Behold..my panel:

```
      <xp:panel
            id="mod"
            rendered="#{javascript:document1.getItemValueString('approval') === 'modify'}">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="modification">
                                Describe modification
                            </label>
                            <xe:djTextarea
                                id="modification"
                                styleClass="form-control"
                                cols="185"
                                rows="25">
                            </xe:djTextarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xp:panel>
```

then, my combobox (see onchange):

```
<xp:comboBox
id="approval"
styleClass="form-control"
style="width:400px;">
<xp:this.onchange>
    <![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:mod}");]]>
</xp:this.onchange>
<xp:selectItem
    itemLabel="Select one"
    itemValue="">
</xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem
    itemLabel="Approve"
    itemValue="approve">
</xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem
    itemLabel="Modify"
    itemValue="modify">
</xp:selectItem>
```

When I change the value of the combobox in the browser, I get this error in a dialog:

[image]

I have a feeling that once I get a better grasp on how to deal with SSJS and element IDs, I will be much more productive.   If anyone has a link to an article that explains this well, I would love to know it.

After all that rambling, question is how do I get this partial refresh to work?

As always, your feedback is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the "mod" panel is not initially rendered so its not available/visible to the onchange event.

Put the "mod" panel in a "modParent" panel and make that the target of your partialRefresh.